# Task cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android

I am trying to make a task manager application and I get one error in line

```
`Task t = new Task(taskName)`
```

although Eclipse say "Task" cannot be resolved to a type and here is not any import show in my eclipse for Task but there show in the tutorial. What can I do? Please help.

My source code is

```
package com.vikram.task.manager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class AddTaskActivity extends Activity {

    private Button addButton;
    private EditText editText;
    private Button cancel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_tasks);
        setUpView();
    }
    protected void cancel() {
        finish();   
    }

    protected void addTask() {
        String taskName = editText.getText().toString();
        Task t = new Task(taskName);
        getTaskManagerApplication().addTask(t);
    }

    private ViewTasksActivity getTaskManagerApplication() {
        ViewTasksActivity tma = (ViewTasksActivity)getApplication();
            return tma;
    }

    private void setUpView() {
        addButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        cancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addTask();
        }
        });
        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cancel();
                }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What tutorial are you following?

Comment: You should provide your source code if you want more people to take a look at this

Comment: What exactly you want your application to do?

Comment: i am trying to make task manager

Answer (score 0):

Try using this: `Thread t = new Thread(taskName);` instead of: `Task t = new Task(taskName);`

Comment: when i change Task to Thread then other error is generated, in just next line at `addTask(t)`.

Comment: have a look at this [ManagingTasks](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#ManagingTasks), and see about Manifest, it might be something with it.

Answer (score 0):

i seen that o'really video actually you are not see the video in sequence. 
in video they are creating the pojo class of Task then they are using this Task class in other activities.

Answer (score 0):

This error comes when we do not have a class and we are using the same as a type of object.

1.In your case Task class is missing,Just highlight the error it will ask you to create a class just select and create a class,It will take you to auto generated code of Task class.

2.According to the code you are following the tutorial from O'rielly website So the missing `Task` class code is here.

```
 import java.io.Serializable;

 public class Task implements Serializable {

/**
 * Generated by Eclipse
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 5527258407135652423L;

private String name;
private boolean complete;

public Task(String taskName) {
    name = taskName;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setComplete(boolean complete) {
    this.complete = complete;
}

public boolean isComplete() {
    return complete;
}

public String toString() {
    return name;
}

public void toggleComplete() {
    complete = !complete;
}

}
```

3. Keep the pakage name as it is and copy this code below the pakage.
4. Now again go the error location task and click on error it will now ask you to import the pakage which you have just now created.

And you are done.